# How does one interpret the return value of img_to_graph in sklearn.feature_extraction.image?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a picture which is of size 34*41(1394 pixels). I used the img_to_graph function as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors
from sklearn.cluster import spectral_clustering
from sklearn.feature_extraction import image
from PIL import Image

pic = Image.open('Chrome.png')
pic = pic.convert('L')
data = np.array(pic).astype(np.float)
affinity = image.img_to_graph(data)
print(affinity)
print(affinity.shape)
print(type(affinity))
print(affinity.toarray())
```

Then I get:

```
  (0, 1)    0.0039215686274509665
  (1, 2)    0.0
  (2, 3)    0.0039215686274509665
  (3, 4)    0.0
  (4, 5)    0.0039215686274509665
  (5, 6)    0.0039215686274509665
...
  (1388, 1388)  0.43529411764705883
  (1389, 1389)  0.42745098039215684
  (1390, 1390)  0.4235294117647059
  (1391, 1391)  0.4196078431372549
  (1392, 1392)  0.41568627450980394
  (1393, 1393)  0.4117647058823529
(1394, 1394)
<class 'scipy.sparse.coo.coo_matrix'>
[[0.81960784 0.00392157 0.         ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.00392157 0.81568627 0.         ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.81568627 ... 0.         0.         0.        ]
 ...
 [0.         0.         0.         ... 0.41960784 0.00392157 0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.         ... 0.00392157 0.41568627 0.00392157]
 [0.         0.         0.         ... 0.         0.00392157 0.41176471]]
```

Why the row and col indexes are different at first and the same in the last several lines? And why affinity does not contain all the nonzero values in affinity.toarray() like affinity.toarray()[0,0](0.81960784) (affinity starts directly with (0, 1)    0.0039215686274509665)

I cannot find useful things in the Sklearn docs. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't tell you what's going on with your values because I don't have your Image. But I can tell you how they are calculated.

Its copy and paste from
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/feature_extraction/image.py.

```
def _make_edges_3d(n_x, n_y, n_z=1):
    """Returns a list of edges for a 3D image.
    Parameters
    ===========
    n_x : integer
        The size of the grid in the x direction.
    n_y : integer
        The size of the grid in the y direction.
    n_z : integer, optional
        The size of the grid in the z direction, defaults to 1
    """
    vertices = np.arange(n_x * n_y * n_z).reshape((n_x, n_y, n_z))
    edges_deep = np.vstack((vertices[:, :, :-1].ravel(),
                            vertices[:, :, 1:].ravel()))
    edges_right = np.vstack((vertices[:, :-1].ravel(),
                             vertices[:, 1:].ravel()))
    edges_down = np.vstack((vertices[:-1].ravel(), vertices[1:].ravel()))
    edges = np.hstack((edges_deep, edges_right, edges_down))
    return edges

img = np.random.rand(20,20)*255
img = img.astype(int)
plt.imshow(img)
img = np.atleast_3d(img)
print(img.shape)
# (20, 20, 1)

n_x, n_y, n_z = img.shape
edges = _make_edges_3d(n_x,n_y,n_z)

# calculate the gradient
edge1 = edges[0,0]
print(edges[0,0]) # 0

edge2 = edges[1,0]
print(edges[1,0]) # 1

a1 = img[edge1 // (n_y * n_z), (edge1 % (n_y * n_z)) // n_z, (edge1 % (n_y * n_z)) % n_z]
a2 = img[edge2 // (n_y * n_z), (edge2 % (n_y * n_z)) // n_z, (edge2 % (n_y * n_z)) % n_z]

pixel = np.abs(a1-a2)

print(pixel == image.img_to_graph(img,return_as=np.ndarray)[0,1]) # True
```